# sequelize instance and class methods alternatives

Tags: methods, sequelize.js

I understand instance and class methods have been removed since v4.  Does anyone know of an alternative to this?  Something similar to attaching methods to moongoose schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Upgrade to v4](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html)

Removed classMethods and instanceMethods options from sequelize.define. Sequelize models are now ES6 classes. You can set class / instance level methods like this

Old

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (model) {...}
    },
    instanceMethods: {
        someMethod: function () { ...}
    }
});
```

New

```
const Model = sequelize.define('Model', {
    ...
});

// Class Method
Model.associate = function (models) {
    ...associate the models
};

// Instance Method
Model.prototype.someMethod = function () {..}
```